# PHP Array to Object Convertion

Tags: php

```
<?php
    
    $array = Array("1" => 1, "2" =>4);
    $array1 = Array("3" => 5);
    $temp = array_merge($array, $array1);

    echo json_encode($temp);
?>
```

It gives the following output

```
[1,4,5]
```

but, I need the following output

```
{"1":1,"2":4,"3":5}
```

Anyone, please answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `+` instead of `array_merge` to preserve keys and make `json_encode()` work properly.

```
<?php
    
    $array = Array(1 => 1, 2 =>4);
    $array1 = Array(3 => 5);
    $temp = $array  + $array1;
    print_r($temp);
    echo json_encode($temp);
```

https://3v4l.org/Fdljn

Note: In case still you are getting output like what you shown in your question, then use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` as second parameter to `json_encode()`